# How to calculate slope from x, y data using weighted least squares linear regression when I have the weights?

Tags: regression, weighted

I've Googled around for WLS and linear regression examples, and I'm very lost in all the equations. I know this is a very naive question.

I'm trying to reproduce analysis of someone else's data. I have an Excel sheet with x and y values tracking growth along 3 time points. I have the weights for WLS, which were available but I've also calculated them manually (I want to make sure I understand what's going on). But, I don't know how to use them.

For example, my sheet looks something like this:

| x | y | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 372.3787334 |
| 2 | 0.276608425 | 89.44492932 |
| 5 | 0.407576831 | 195.3374008 |

And the expected slope is 0.947284051

I've tried multiplying the y data by the weight (w) and using Excel's linear regression to determine the slope, but I can never get exactly this 0.947284051 number. In addition to y * w, I've tried y * w^2, y * w^(1/2), y * (1/w), etc.

How do I actually make use of the weight? I've seen elsewhere people using matrices, but that seems more complicated than a simple dataset like this requires... but also I've got no idea what to do, just a hunch it's something really simple...